# Minimize to tray make form unvisible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon

I am using `NotifyIcon` to make my form minimize to tray to work at background.

However below code doesn't show app icon at all. Form goes totally invisible. I have to kill that from task manager.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
    {   
        Hide();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true; 
    }
}
```

What could be the reason? I want to see my app-icon to re-open the form.

Comment: [Single Instance Windows Forms Application with Minimize to Tray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33028650/3110834)

Comment: Also make sure you have set an `Icon` for `NotifyIcon`.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/how-to-minimize-your-application-to-system-tray-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign an `Icon` to [`NotifyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to show it in system tray. Also you need to set `Visible` to `true`.

You can set properties using property grid at design time or you can set them by code. For example, you can use such code:

```
this.notifyIcon1.Icon = this.Icon;
this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
```

If you don't set the Icon or if the visible is not true, it will not show the icon.