# Tooltip notification icon not appearing

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried this code but nothing is happened

```
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Please Wait", "Creating Database...", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

And tried this code also

```
NotifyIcon Notification = new NotifyIcon();
Notification.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
Notification.BalloonTipTitle = "Please Wait";
Notification.BalloonTipText = "Creating Database...";
Notification.Visible = true;
Notification.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "Please Wait", "Creating Database...", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

Nothing ever appeared

Comment: Is this a .net framework windows forms application? wpf? something else? Where is the code found in the context of the form/control? Is it ever called (did you verify it with the debugger)? What exactly does happen in the application? Where is the `Notification` instance added to the control/form (it probably needs to be associated with a controls collection somewhere)

Comment: @Igor windows forms application,nothing happened.just tried click button to show notifyIcon

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48892114/3110834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because you didn't specify the `Icon` property. Try to add this:

```
Notification.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
```

(I'm assuming you're using WinForms because you didn't specify.)

Comment: now works well.But what mean that ?

Comment: @Geanny It means you need an icon, any icon.

Comment: @Geanny It defines the icon that is shown in the notifications area of the taskbar (other than the `BalloonTipIcon` that you did specify) and you need to show some icon there, as @LarsTech said.

Comment: @LarsTech thank you