# Doubleclick on notifyicon works only the second time

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I'm developing a Windows form application and I would like that when it is resized, a notifyIcon will appear in the tray. Then when double-clicking on the notifiyIcon the form is showed. 
I've linked the events to the handlers:

```
this.Resize += Form1_Resize;
this.notifyIcon.MouseDoubleClick += notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick;
```

With my code:

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
```

the form is minimized in the tray and the icon disappear from the taskbar, that is perfect. 
But when I try to resume the form double-clicking on the notifyIcon, the first time nothing happen. The second time I double-click the form will show. This is the code for the handler of the double-click event:

```
private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    { 
        this.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

I think is something relative to the WindowState, that I set after the Show() function. But if I set the WindowState before that is even worse, nothing happen neither the second time I double-click.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Problem solved using this.ShowInTaskbar = false; instead of this.Hide(); and of course I had to put this.ShowInTaskbar = true; in the notifyIcon_mouseDoubleClick. Is it a good solution?

Comment: Read the notify icon part in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33028650/3110834).

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei , this post is really interesting. I hadn't thought of the double instance issue, I will also try that solution.